# Upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 13.10, 15.04

I have dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10.  I want to upgrade the version of Ubuntu to 15.04. Will that affect my data? And is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two paritions, one for Windows and the other for Ubuntu, if your data is on the Windows 7 partition, and you're running update manager in Ubuntu, it shouldn't affect your NTFS partition at all. If running update manager, it will only affect the system files on your Ubuntu partition.

If you have data on the Ubuntu partition, it shouldn't affect those either, unless you decided to save your data in a system folder that gets deleted for some reason. As long as it's in your `/home/xxxxx/` folder, it should be safe.